# Receiving an SMS on an Arduino Yun with the Twilio service

Tags: python, arduino, twilio, arduino-yun

I'm trying to create a project with an Arduino Yun that will allow it to receive text messages and process commands based on the text.  I've followed the tutorial for sending SMS messages with the Yun (https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/02/send-sms-and-mms-from-your-arduino-yun.html) but I can't find any resources for receiving a text.  Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

In general , you can always receive an SMS on a SMS capable Twilio number you buy from the console . What should be done on the receipt of that SMS is usually required to be programmed.

In your case , twilio_phone_number used to send SMS out could receive the replies.

For programming the replies , 
(A)first setup a webserver and create an endpoint that could parse the incoming message and then trigger necessary action on your Arduino .A quick google search shows this useful link ( http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-Arduino-with-python-based-web-API-No-p/?ALLSTEPS )   . Test  this endpoint to be sure it does what you want it to do when given right params.

(B) You should then setup the webhook for this number for incoming messages ( see attached [When  A MESSAGE COMES IN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrjCD.png) ) to the endpoint created in step 1 .

Comment: Some useful articles for you are 

 - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134127-Receive-SMS-messages-without-Responding
 - https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/hello-monkey